# React Redux: Inconsistent Value of Variable Inside and Outside Function in Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I am encountering an issue in a custom React hook that uses Redux. The problem is related to the inconsistency of a variable's value inside and outside a function within the same hook. Here's the simplified code:

```
import { useAppSelector } from "Redux/helpers";
import { selectAgentState } from "Redux/slices/agentSlice";

const useRemoveRoomNotif = () => {
  const notifications = useAppSelector((state) => selectAgentState(state).notifications);
  console.log("Outside function:", notifications);

  const removeNotif = (rid: string, markNotificationsAsRead) => {
    console.log("Inside function:", notifications);
    const ntf = notifications.filter((notif) => notif.roomID === rid && !notif.isRead);
    if (ntf.length !== 0) markNotificationsAsRead(ntf);
  };

  return { removeNotif };
};

export default useRemoveRoomNotif;
```

he issue is that the notifications value inside the `removeNotif` function is different from the value outside the function. I assumed that since it's the same variable, the values should be the same.

I attempted a workaround using `useState`, `useEffect`, and `useRef` to ensure the correct value is used inside the function:

```
const useRemoveRoomNotif = () => {
  const notifications = useAppSelector((state) => selectAgentState(state).notifications);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);
  const [id, seId] = useState("");
  const markAsReadRef = useRef<(notifications: INotification[]) => void>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!update) return;
    const ntf = notifications.filter((notif) => notif.roomID === id && !notif.isRead);
    if (ntf.length !== 0 && markAsReadRef.current) {
      markAsReadRef.current(ntf);
    }
    setUpdate(false);
  }, [notifications, markAsReadRef, id, update, setUpdate]);

  const removeNotif = useCallback(
    (rid: string, markNotificationsAsRead: (notifications: INotification[]) => void) => {
      seId(rid);
      markAsReadRef.current = markNotificationsAsRead;
      setUpdate(true);
    },
    [notifications, seId, markAsReadRef]
  );

  return { removeNotif };
};

export default useRemoveRoomNotif;
```

Can someone please help me understand why the initial implementation is not working as expected and if the workaround is necessary? Any insights or suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply stated, you have an issue of a stale closure over the selected `notifications` state value in the `removeNotif` callback function. In other words, `removeNotif` never sees any updated `notifications` value in its lifetime.

Your attempted workaround is also quite convoluted. I believe you could achieve a working solution using just the React `useCallback` hook to re-enclose the current `notifications` state value in the `removeNotif` callback handler.

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useAppSelector } from "Redux/helpers";
import { selectAgentState } from "Redux/slices/agentSlice";

const useRemoveRoomNotif = () => {
  const { notifications } = useAppSelector(selectAgentState);
  console.log("Outside function:", notifications);

  const removeNotif = useCallback((rid: string, markNotificationsAsRead) => {
    console.log("Inside function:", notifications);
    const ntf = notifications.filter((notif) => notif.roomID === rid && !notif.isRead);
    if (!!ntf.length) markNotificationsAsRead(ntf);
  }, [notifications]);

  return { removeNotif };
};
```

If the code you have isn't using the updated `removeNotif` callback references, i.e. it is used as an event listener, then an alternative would be to "cache" the current `notifications` value in a React ref and reference the ref's current value in the `removeNotif` handler.

Example:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useAppSelector } from "Redux/helpers";
import { selectAgentState } from "Redux/slices/agentSlice";

const useRemoveRoomNotif = () => {
  const { notifications } = useAppSelector(selectAgentState);
  const notificationsRef = useRef(notifications);
  console.log("Outside function:", notifications);

  // Cache current notifications value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    notificationsRef.current = notifications;
  }, [notifications]);

  const removeNotif = useCallback((rid: string, markNotificationsAsRead) => {
    // Get current notifications ref value
    const notifications = notificationsRef.current;

    console.log("Inside function:", notifications);
    const ntf = notifications.filter((notif) => notif.roomID === rid && !notif.isRead);
    if (!!ntf.length) markNotificationsAsRead(ntf);
  }, [notifications]);

  return { removeNotif };
};
```

Comment: This actually isn't going to help bc the consuming code isn't updating its removeNotif closure (that's obvious because that closure is created anew in every render with the OP's implementation).

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Thanks for the feedback. Both implementations should generally help, and the second helps address the specific issue you refer to if consumers aren't updating their reference of the callback.